# Shell script not redirecting correct output to a file

Tags: shell, process

I have a simple question. Here is a shell script

```
ps -a > temp
```

The actual output on a shell is something like:

```
rishis    234 564  0 22:56 pts/1    00:00:04 <command>
```

However, when I look at the temp file, the output is only:

```
234 pts/1 00:00:04 <part of command>
```

Can anyone explain what the reason might be ?

Comment: Which OS are you working on? It works fine for me on OS X.

Comment: i am not sure but try this - run it with a absolute path `/bin/ps -a > temp`

Comment: My bad. The culprit was an alias entry in .bashrc (ps = 'ps -aef') which caused a verbose response on a normal ps on shell prompt.The output from the script is correct. So yeah using absolute ps path would have helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what OS and version of the software you're using on but it probably boils down to this: many common commands are designed to work slightly differently depending on whether they're being called interactively or in a pipeline. (in this context, redirecting and piping would have the same results, as the command decide their behavior based on whether stdout is bound to a terminal)

The most pervasive example would be ls: by default it lists files in column in interactive mode and one for per line in pipe mode. Check your man page for documented behavior with ps.

You can emulate pipe mode while keeping output to stdout by piping to cat:

```
ps -a | cat
```

Another explanation, if you're under a weird enough shell, is that it has a builtin for ps, but doesn't wish to use it in certain contexts, like redirection. Check for that by using a complete `/bin/ps` invocation. `time` tends to work like this.

Comment: My bad. The culprit was an alias entry in .bashrc (ps = 'ps -aef') which caused a verbose reponse on a normal ps on shell prompt. the output from the script is correct. So yeah using absolue ps path would have helped. Thanks